# Client-Server connection does not work through internet

Tags: c#, client-server, tcplistener

I am trying to make own simple client-server app using standard TcpListener/TcpClient classes. First of all, I have to say that I am a beginner in network programming. So, I made it but it only works locally (both computers are in the same network and I am using ipv4 address from ipconfig (is it local one?) to create TcpListener and using the same address to connect from client app for TcpClient.

How can I make it to work with my actual IP address (given by provider, whatismyip.com shows me)? Should I use 127.0.0.1 on server and my external IP on client?

Thanks for patience.

Answer (score 0):

Ok two things you need to do, firstly you need your server to allow connection from any ip. secondly you need you client to connect to the ip and port of you server. **Dont forget to port forward the port you are using for your server!**

Firstly the server

```
private static Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

void init()
{
    serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORTHERE));
    serverSocket.Listen(1);
    serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(CallBack), null);
}
```

And then you need to connect to it on the client

```
private Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

void init()
{
    while (!clientSocket.Connected)
    {
        try
        {
            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse(IPHERE);
            clientSocket.Connect(ipAd, PORTHERE);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
}
```

Also here is a example of a simple client from my library: https://github.com/TheRealNOIG/TylerGregorcyksLibrary/blob/master/TylerGregorcyksLibrary/Main/SimpleClient.cs